# Google Cloud Messaging - storing limitations

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I developed an app that allows to see or download some files from my VPS. Every day, I'm adding new files (one or two times per day) and I want to notify my users, that there are new files available.
I heard about Google Cloud Messaging, but there is a limit - only 100 messages can be stored. But I think that I get it wrong. This is 100 messages per one device or 100 messages in GCM server?

So far I have more than 8000 active users and I am afraid that some of them will not get notification.

> Note: There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user not understanding documentation.

Comment: I edited my post, because I read it by myself and you had right - that was messy :P

Answer (score 1):

The 100 message limit is per device and not per application. So if you send 100 messages from your app to a specific device which is offline then all 100 will be dropped.

If I am sending out a message to a few thousand devices, it is expected at least 100 of them to be (temporarily) offline. It doesn't make sense discarding the whole batch.

[Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)

Comment: You are mostly correct. If you send 100 messages, they won't all be dropped. If you send 101, they might be, but usually it'll just drop the oldest. That's what collapse-keys are for.